# Margin-right not working in ul element - Css

Tags: html, css

I have wordpress website and I've a form, form elements are in `ul li` tags, I have did this to make it grid:

```
form.wpuf-form-add ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -10px !important;
}
form.wpuf-form-add ul li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

But margin-right is not working in `ul`, for that reason my elements are not in full container.. Here is the screenshot:
[image]
Can you please help me what's wrong with it, please help me..

Comment: please share your live website link.

Comment: http://plane.wzy.ntf.mybluehost.me/planes-new-ad/ --  use this link

Comment: can u link me the particular page?i still cant find it.

Comment: looks like problem is solved :)

Comment: Yeah, it solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add auto width on `.ul.wpuf-form` like

```
form.wpuf-form-add ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -10px !important;
    width: auto;
}
```